# Find Site ID From WP_Post

Tags: php, posts, multisite

### Background

I am writing a migration tool that can move (copy, then delete) posts from one site on a multi-site network to another. I want to correctly separate concerns, and from that point of view it seems that in order to migrate a post from one site to another you need two things:

1. The post - in WP represented by a `WP_Post` object.
2. The site ID - ID of the site to migrate it to.

### Question

How can I, being given only a `WP_Post` instance, get the ID of the site it belongs to?

### Remarks

Foreseeing answers that just use `get_current_blog_id()`: that will get the ID of the *current* site, whatever that is. I want the ID of the site that the given post *belongs* to.

For those saying "if you're working with a post, you probably know where it came from, because you queried for it":

```php
function doSomethingWithPost(WP_Post $post)
{
  // No, I do not know that
}
```

It appears that the `WP_Post` object does not contain the information necessary to track it to its site. Ticket [#51373](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51373) raised in relation to this problem.

Comment: As far as I’m aware Posts don’t have a record of which site they belong to apart from the database table that they’re  in. But it’s very unlikely that you’ve ended up with a WP_Post object without first knowing which site it belongs to. If you’re getting a WP_Post object then you must’ve queried the post somehow, and to do that you need to know which site to query, so you must already have a record of which site you’re getting the post from. Could you elaborate on the context where you’ve got a post object without knowing where it came from?

Comment: > If you’re getting a WP_Post object then you must’ve queried the post somehow, and to do that you need to know which site to query, so you must already have a record of which site you’re getting the post from

Nope. See updated question.

Comment: Your example still involves you sending the post to your function. It didn't come from nowhere. At some stage you _must_ be retrieving the post from a known source, even if it's just the current site, so you should be able to pass that information alongside the post.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. Have you heard of Separation of Concerns? I mention it in the question's Background. If I have a function that accepts a `WP_Post`, it doesn't meant that the code invoking that function is in the same package, or that it's under my control.

Comment: @XedinUnknown where are the post objects coming from? And why do you not know the site ID already? If you're writing a migration tool then you have all the information needed, putting it in the post object is unnecessary. Just pass the site ID as a second parameter to your function. If you do not know it, then you're going to have to explain why

Comment: If you have a function that needs a post, and which site it belongs to, then it should also just accept a site ID. It makes no sense to just accept the post and complain you don’t have the information you need when you could just require it to be sent.

Comment: From a SoC point of view, it _does_ make sense to just accept a `WP_Post` instance, because a post belongs to a site. But I do realize that this is not currently possible, and accepting a site ID _additionally_ is currently the best way, if this is possible.

Comment: Only in a circustantial sense, `WP_Post` objects are just data containers, they don't belong to anything, or provide any guarantees. E.g. there's no guarantee that a `WP_Post` object has a row in the database, you can do `$p = new \WP_Post()` or use a post object after the post is deleted. The APIs around post objects don't account for posts on any site other than what's considered current

Comment: Not true. A `WP_Post ` represents an actual post. While it is possible to create an instance that doesn't actually point to any real post, most code depending on it would break, or just not behave as expected. For example, if I want to retrieve the custom fields of a `WP_Post` `$post`, I would do `get_post_custom($post->ID)`. If this doesn't point to anything, that code will break. In any case, even if the post doesn't point to a real post, it's only relevant on a site, and therefore should expose that site's ID - even if it's not a real ID of a real site.

Answer (score 1):

**No, post objects do not store this data. You need to store the site ID separately.**

Post objects do not store the site they were created on or are currently hosted on. That information doesn't exist in the posts table, nor does WordPress track it elsewhere. The assumption is always that the post comes from the current site.

The code you're writing will need to store the source site ID somehow. Some plugins do this via post meta.

If you already have posts that have been migrated though, would have to load up each site, and query for the post with the same ID, then compare them, and if they match, you've found it. This assumes no modifications have been made at either end.

***Q: How do we know this?***

Because there is nowhere in `WP_Post` that stores the site ID or network ID. Inspecting a variable holding a post object shows this information isn't available either.

***Q: What do other plugins/developers do?***

If they need to migrate a post to another site, but also need to trace it back to its source, they store those details in post meta.

For example, the original URL, site ID, and post ID can be stored as post meta. This is useful for UI purposes, telling a user that the post has been migrated or syndicated. This is what the [syndicator](https://github.com/Automattic/syndication) and [distributor](https://github.com/10up/distributor) plugins do.

***Q: Can the GUID be used?***

No, GUID's aren't always URLs, aren't always current, and don't always represent the source.

For example, a GUID will not change if a posts slug or URL changes, the GUID can be a hash not a URL, the GUID may be a remote URL, or it may be a URL from an old permalink structure or an old site URL.

***Q: Do we need to get the site ID from a post object?***

No! If you have a post object then at some point you were in the context of the site it came from. Pass the site ID as a second parameter.

Ideally, your function should receive a post ID and a site ID, not a post object:

```php
function doSomethingWithPost( int $post_id, int $site_id=0 ) {
    switch_to_blog( $site_id );
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    // ....
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Or, the site should be assumed to be the current site, and `switch_to_blog` called beforehand, e.g.:

```php
switch_to_blog( $site_id );
doSomethingWithPost($post_id);
restore_current_blog();
```

I recommend passing the site ID as a function parameter so that good dependency injection can be practiced.

Comment: How about the GUID?

Comment: A GUID is unreliable and not intended for this purpose, it's also not safe to assume a GUID is a URL, or that the URL is from the original site, or that it's the posts URL, or that it's even valid

Comment: Yep. I knew all of those things. And it is driving me mad. Especially about deserialization. When de-serializing posts, you _cannot_ know where it came from, and consequently - what site to switch to.

Comment: I strongly advise that you do not serialise and deserialize `WP_Post` objects for security and performance reasons. When deserialized, none of the caches are primed like they would be if it were fetched from the database. Every `get_post_meta` call and every attempt to fetch terms will result in a small database query, this is because when WP fetches a post it also fetches the meta/terms in advance. Store a post ID + site ID, and if you must serialize, store a JSON representation

Comment: @XedinUnknown storing the site ID is unavoidable and necessary. There is no way to cheat and get around it without paying a performance/scaling cost through queries. Just store a post ID and the site ID to switch to to retrieve it

Comment: Yea, but I'm not talking about only serialization. There are other concerns. After all, a `WP_Post` object should represent an actual entity. And if there's no way to connect that representation to the entity, then it's wrong.

Comment: So, I created a ticket on Trac (see updated question). Let's see if this gets any TracTion.

Comment: I doubt they will add it, you should not rely on that ticket. I wasn't joking when I said you need to store the site ID along with the post ID. ***Do not store a `WP_Post` object as a serialized string, store a post ID instead.*** Serializing a `WP_Post` object is already super bad practice.

Comment: @XedinUnknown if my answer answers your question could you mark it as accepted? You can't get a site ID back from just a post object, that's not how post objects work. I suspect there's a critical piece of information related to how your migration tool works that you've not shared that's behind this question ( are you migrating posts to other sites by serializing them then sending that string to be processed at the other end? if so, no no no no no huge no no )

Comment: @TomJNowell, my particular case is not for serialization per se, but for anything that needs to do things with a post of a site. I understand that there is no way to derive site information from a `WP_Post`, so there may not be an answer at all. Going through each site and comparing the post data is hardly a solution, even though in some extreme cases it could be the only way to do things. So, I'm not sure if there is going to be an accepted answer. However, I did upvote your answer. Also, I know I shouldn't rely on the feature request; it's there for reference.

Comment: Normally whatever migrated the post will store a post meta value with the original site ID on the target site so that you can look at that post meta to see which site the post originally came from, however the post object and WordPress do not store this information, it has to be explicitly added by you. I've amended my answer accordingly, but, ***the canonical answer is no you can't***, you have to store the site ID somewhere, it can't be derived from a post object. You can confirm this by inspecting the innards of `WP_Post`